# Snap squares to a grid algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm writing a game which involves a two dimensional board of tiles that can be moved around.  The physics engine is handling the movement, but at the end of a movement, I am trying to snap the tiles to the grid.

Now hold on!  I already am snapping to grid correctly in most cases.  I simply calculate the row and column from the position of the square using a form of modulus (actually repeated adding with compare) and determine where the center of each tile is in the grid.

Here is the hard part.  There are "edge cases" (literally) where there can be two tiles that end up in the same square.  This is because the tiles are slightly smaller than the squares, so if you move one just past the edge line, the next one is pushed but not enough to pass the edge line, so you end up with two squares that belong to the same grid.

In extreme cases, there is an even harder problem.

Take this grid where X is the center of the tile.

```
 _______
| |X| | |
| |X| | |
| |X|X| |
|_|X|_|_|
```

Now imagine it at the end of a move looks like this (where X is "on the line")

```
 _______
| X | | |
| X | | |
| X X | |
|_X_|_|_|
```

You can see that not only do two squares belong to the 3rd row, and 2nd column, but you can't just "push" the tiles in one direction or another without counting, checking etc.

If you imagine a grid like this (all of the tiles are on the line, you see this could get out of hand.

```
 _______
| X X X |
| X X X |
| X X X |
|_X_X_X_|
```

Ideas?

EDIT

This is a realistic and common case:

```
 _______
| |X| | |
| |X| | |
| X X | |
|_|X|_|_|
```

Now, both snap to the same column, leaving a "squish" situation where we attempt to snap 5 tiles into a 4 row column...

Comment: Put the tiles into a priority queue based on how close they are to center, then put the best ones in first.  That solves most cases.  You will still need some complicated "I need to push you over" logic for the case when one tile is on an edge, and on either side a tile slid over and got placed first.  Think `| X X|  X |`.

Comment: Having now read this after your other question, I'm not sure how a situation like the 2nd diagram can ever arise if tiles are snapped-to-grid *after each movement*.  How did a single movement cause 5 tiles to overlap 2 grid spaces each?

Comment: Well, there is no restriction on how you move.  You could push each tile over halfway, then leave the "touch tile" where it was also overlapping.  That actually isn't a realistic simulation.  I'm going to edit.

Comment: And for the sake of clarity, you can eliminate the possibly of anything other than one direction (north, east, south, west) per "touch" or "move".

Comment: I see now, thanks.  While this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, if the only "meaningful" positions of the tiles are the snapped-to-grid positions, then it seems that you're adding an awful lot of complexity by allowing intermediate non-snapped-to-grid positions...  the fixing up of which possibly also leads to a counterintuitive user experience.  To simplify everything without completely giving up "smoothness", how about making all tiles "sticky", so that if you push a tile but not over the halfway point, it slides back to its original position?

Comment: Actually, removal of the physics engine meant the actual tiles could be exactly the same size as the grid position. This way, snapping to grid poses no problem because no tiles can have their center within the same grid square. I did achieve smoothness using the function I posted in the other thread.  Snap to position doesn't "break" the feel, whereas snapping constantly would feel jittery I think.  Still, the most important part of anything is knowing it can be done ;)