# Moving tiles around without a physics engine

Tags: algorithm, game-physics

I am currently developing part of a game which involves moving tiles around which can push other tiles, basically just like those puzzle boards with one piece missing where you need to rebuild the image.

[image: the yosemite tile game]

The question: Is there a way, without using box2d and collision detection to get the tiles to move around properly?

This is related to my previous question:

[Snap squares to a grid algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559230/snap-squares-to-a-grid-algorithm)

which I am asking because the physics engine leaves the tiles all over the place.

There can be several pieces missing (unlike this picture, where there is exactly one)

Comment: Using a physics engine for this would be like using a physics engine to add two numbers.  If the user moves a tile at grid position (x, y) in some direction, move that tile *and all tiles that form a contiguous block when moving in that direction*.  E.g. if moving right, `for (i = x; i < width && isTileAt[i][y]; ++i) { moveTileRight(i, y); }`

Comment: I am not clear on how this provides a solution.  How do you determine whether there is a contiguous block in a particular direction?  Suppose you start moving right, and then move left.  Those tiles are no longer "touching" and so moving right again should not move them.  My point being, you end up having to solve for collision again, so ...physics engine.

Comment: It's not clear from your question (perhaps it's in the linked question but I didn't look), but I take it that a user's "movement" of a block can be less than a full grid square -- e.g. a few pixels only?  That doesn't change things fundamentally: whenever you move, say, right 10 pixels, you start with `z = 10`, and keep moving tiles whose leftmost edge is `<= z` pixels to the right of the current tile's rightmost edge, reducing `z` by the size of the gap each time.  Once `z` goes negative, you can stop.

Comment: But then what about the edges of the board?  How do you tell the first tile that it can't move anymore?  I think you might be on to something, though.  Perhaps an "accumulated width in this direction" function and "tiles in this direction" function.

Answer (score 0):

It boiled down to a recursive function within a greater "Board".  Thanks for input.  Mostly just needed to know it was easy.

```
func moveTile(tile:Tile, amount:CGFloat, direction:Direction) -> CGFloat {
    var checkLocation:CGPoint = tile.position
    var spaceBetween:CGFloat = 0
    switch direction {
    case .North:
        checkLocation.y += amount + (tileSize.height / 2)
    case .South :
        checkLocation.y -= amount + (tileSize.height / 2)
    case .East:
        checkLocation.x += amount + (tileSize.width / 2)
    case .West:
        checkLocation.x -= amount + (tileSize.width / 2)
    }
    var maxAmount = amount
    if !boundingEdgeRect.contains(checkLocation) {
        switch direction {
        case .North:
            maxAmount -= checkLocation.y - boundingEdgeRect.height - boundingEdgeRect.origin.y
        case .South :
            maxAmount -= boundingEdgeRect.origin.y - checkLocation.y
        case .East:
            maxAmount -= checkLocation.x - boundingEdgeRect.width - boundingEdgeRect.origin.x
        case .West:
            maxAmount -= boundingEdgeRect.origin.x - checkLocation.x
        }
    } else {
        let nodes = self.nodesAtPoint(checkLocation)
        for node in nodes {
            if let nextTile = node as? Tile {
                switch direction {
                case .North:
                    spaceBetween = nextTile.position.y - tile.position.y - tileSize.height
                case .South :
                    spaceBetween = tile.position.y - nextTile.position.y - tileSize.height
                case .East:
                    spaceBetween = nextTile.position.x - tile.position.x - tileSize.width
                case .West:
                    spaceBetween = tile.position.x - nextTile.position.x - tileSize.width
                }
                let tileAmount = moveTile(nextTile, amount:amount - spaceBetween, direction:direction) + spaceBetween
                if tileAmount < maxAmount {
                    maxAmount = tileAmount
                }
            }
        }
    }
    switch direction {
    case .North:
        tile.position.y += maxAmount
    case .South :
        tile.position.y -= maxAmount
    case .East:
        tile.position.x += maxAmount
    case .West:
        tile.position.x -= maxAmount
    }
    return maxAmount
}
```

Tiles are center anchored, position is relative to the board, which is also center anchored.